# Case expression not constant

Tags: c++

I am getting a 'case expression not constant' error in a switch statement. However, the header provides a definition for the used constants, and the constructor provides initialisation for them in its initialization list.

Additionally, when I mouse over the "problem" statements it identifies them as constants.

```
const int ThisClass::EXAMPLE_CONSTANT

error expression must have a constant value
```

This seems a little counter-intuitive to me. I did some research and found a similar problem that someone else had. They were told that all constants must in fact be initialised in 'main' and that this was a limitation of the language. Is this really the case? It seems unlikely.

Comment: provide actual code that demonstrates the problem. What you pasted is not really helpful.

Comment: What compiler are you using? Is it really C++?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `case` statements require integral value which must be known at compile-time, which is what is meant by *constant* here. But the `const` members of a *class* are not really *constant* in that sense. They're are simply read-only.

Instead of fields, you can use `enum` :

```
class ThisClass
{
    public:

        enum Constants
        {
            EXAMPLE_CONSTANT = 10,
            ANOTHER_CONSTANT = 20
        };    
};
```

And then you can write,

```
switch(c)
{
      case ThisClass::EXAMPLE_CONSTANT:
                   //code
                   break;
      case ThisClass::ANOTHER_CONSTANT:
                   //code
                   break;
};
```

Comment: if the constants are not related, I'd propose to use an unnamed enum.

Comment: (This C++ feature) It's kind of lame, in my case, `const int ThisClass::EXAMPLE_CONSTANT` is a API code, I can't change it.

Comment: @Zhang: If your constants are not actually const known at compile time and are actually read-only, then you cannot use `switch()` like I showed above. However, you can use a map with your constants as keys and a function as values!

Answer (score 5):

You need a "real" compile time integer constant. `const` in C++ means read-only, and a const variable can
be initialized just like `int y = 0; const int x = y;`, making `x` a read-only copy of the value `y` had at the time of initialization.

With a modern compiler, you can either use `enum`s or `constexpr`s to store (integral) members of compile-time-constness:

```
class Foo {
public:
    static constexpr int x = 0;
    enum { y = 1 };
};

int main () {
    switch (0) {
    case Foo::x: ;
    case Foo::y: ;
    }
}
```

Comment: `constexpr` doesn't make the member static.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit of a mess. In C++ `const` can be used for several things, like declaring actual constants, and declaring read-only variables.

If you declare:

```
const int x = 0;
```

In global, namespace, or local scope, it is a constant. You can use it where constant expressions are required (like case labels or array sizes). However, at class scope or as a function parameter, it's just a read-only variable.

Additionally, if you declare at class scope:

```
static const int x = 0;
```

This is also a constant.

Comment: A `const int` variable declared in function scope (i.e in local scope)  and initialized with an integral constant expression does itself form integral constant expressions in C++. So in function scope it is not just a "read-only variable".

Comment: @AndreyT oops, I meant function parameter :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Constants used in case labels must be *integral constant expressions*. An *integral constant expression* must satisfy a much more strict set of requirements than just being an integral object declared as `const`.

A non-static class member cannot be used in an integral constant expression, so what you are trying to do will not compile. A static class member, for example, can be used in an integral constant expression if its initializer is "visible" at the point of use.

Answer (score 1):

**`std::map` + C++11 lambdas workaround**

This method allows for non constants, should give us `O(1)` amortized [What is the best way to use a HashMap in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578083/what-is-the-best-way-to-use-a-hashmap-in-c) :

```
#include <ctime>
#include <functional>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int result;
    int key0 = std::time(NULL) % 3;
    int key1 = (key0 + 1) % 3;
    int key2 = (key0 + 2) % 3;
    std::unordered_map<int,std::function<void()>> m{
        {key0, [&](){ result = 0; }},
        {key1, [&](){ result = 1; }},
        {key2, [&](){ result = 2; }},
    };
    m[key0]();
    std::cout << key0 << " " << result << std::endl;
    m[key1]();
    std::cout << key1 << " " << result << std::endl;
    m[key2]();
    std::cout << key2 << " " << result << std::endl;
}
```

Possible output:

```
1 0
2 1
0 2
```

For usage from inside a class, don't forget to build the map statically as shown at: [Why switch statement cannot be applied on strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650162/why-switch-statement-cannot-be-applied-on-strings/42462552#42462552)